# Error in rewrite uri with nginx

Tags: nginx, rewrite

Here is the error we have when loading nginx on ubuntu 12.04 server:

```
nginx: [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "location" directive in /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf:58
```

What we are trying to do is to append a string to the end of uri entered. For example, if `mysite.com/abcd` or `mysite.com/abcd/` are entered, `nginx` should `rewrite` them to `mysite.com/abcd/auth/signin`

Here is what we have in `nginx.conf`:

```
location {
          rewrite "/[a-zA-Z]\w{1,9}/" /$1/auth/signin last;
          rewrite "/[a-zA-Z]\w{1,9}" /$1/auth/signin last;
        }
     }
```

What's wrong with the location block above and how we should name the location block? Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:

Here is `server` block in nginx.conf:

```
 server {
        listen 80;
        server_name mysite.com;
        root /var/www/;
        passenger_enabled on;
        rails_env production;
        passenger_base_uri /nbhy;

 ...
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A location block needs a uri. So, you may want this:

```
location / {
    rewrite "/[a-zA-Z]\w{1,9}/" /$1/auth/signin last;
    rewrite "/[a-zA-Z]\w{1,9}" /$1/auth/signin last;
}
```

Or, if you don't want to apply these rewrites to a certain path, just remove the location part altogether. I.e.

```
rewrite "/[a-zA-Z]\w{1,9}/" /$1/auth/signin last;
rewrite "/[a-zA-Z]\w{1,9}" /$1/auth/signin last;
```

Comment: What's the uri for the location block? Does it mean anything?

Comment: Now the nginx error disappeared. But there is an 500 error with mysite.com/abcd. There is no change on the url displayed in browser. Firebug did not show what's the uri it rewrote.